# How to prevent Riva Tuner from overlaying certain applications

Tags: overlay, osd, msi-afterburner

I recently installed [MSI Afterburner](https://www.msi.com/Landing/afterburner/graphics-cards) with Riva Tuner to monitor my RAM usage during some game testing. I have noticed since installing this that there are other programs that Riva Tuner is also overlaying that don't want, like SMPlayer for example:

[image]

Its showing up in applications like 3dsMax too:

[image]

Other applications I have seen it overlay are MilkShape3d, Noesis and other 3d editing software.

How can I create a rule that excludes all apps from having overlays except the one I want?

Comment: [This](https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/how-can-i-stop-msi-afterburner-overlay-from-appearing-on-other-apps.442694/) should help

Comment: @Ramhound thanks. While you were typing that, I was writing down the same thing in my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution. Here are the steps I took:

- Open MSI Afterburner. You can minimize the application, and then navigate to the application icon tray in the lower right corner. Click on the Riva Tuner icon to open the Riva Tuner Properties panel:
  [image]
- Once the Riva Tuner panel is open, click on 'Global' parameter at the top of the list and make sure its setting is set to **NONE**:

[image]

- Restart any applications that previously were open with the overlay. Once restarted there will no longer be any overlays.
- To INCLUDE a specific application, simply press the **ADD** button in the lower left corner of the Riva Tuner window:

[image]

- A Windows Explorer dialogue box will appear asking for the path of the application you wish to include in the list of programs with allowed overlays. Select the application and press OK.
- After this the recently added application will appear in the list in the Riva Tuner panel under the Global section mentioned above. Click on this newly added entry and make sure that its setting is set to anything but **NONE**.
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a .exe in RivaTuner and Turn the OSD off to override the global settings for this one application.

[image: RivaTuner OSD]